# Informatica Power center issue

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

The source is Table (Sqlserver) and Target is a file.

I need to load yesterday data count into the target file and I tried using below query in Source qualifier transformation.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from Table name where DATEID= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) ;
```

The Table has yesterday data count but loading as 0 into the file.

Zero records loading... Can you please let me know..Informatica experts?

Comment: You're asking a group of people to second guess what your mapping logic does, what is stored in your table... a leap for anyone to be fair... can you share the load summary from your session log, especially the source section

Comment: I just want Count of the records for yesterday only..

Comment: Ok, I'll wave my hand at the sql, for us to know if its the sql causing you problems and not something else in your mapping - how about you run that query on the db and see if it returns any results. If not then this issue is constrained to the query and infornatica plays no role. If it does return results when ran from db then check your session logs for the actual query text ran and confirm from the source section of the load summary how many records were picked up at the source qualifier. If its more than 0 then there is a bottleneck somewhere in the mapping which will take more work

Comment: This question needs to be improved. Please use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for reference. Then improve the question by showing what you've got, what happens, show the log, etc. Otherwise it's really frustrating for the people who REALLY would like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the following where clause?

```
TO_CHAR (DATEID,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR (GETDATE()-1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: I tried which is you given function but not working in Sql servr ..Pls find the below error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'TO_CHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I think TO_CHAR is supported only in oracle. Please try using this: WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEID, 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 120)

Comment: i tried your query is working in DB it's self but not working while loading into the target file and it is loading as 0 records into the file. Pls see the below log:Severity: INFO
Timestamp: 9/11/2017 4:23:21 PM
Node: node01_potapld00046
Thread: READER_4_1_1
Process ID: 6484
Message Code: RR_4029
Message: SQ Instance table name User specified SQL Query [SELECT COUNT(*) from table name where DateID= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-13, 120)]

Comment: I tried the above one and It's working as in DB level only.not working while loading into the file.

Comment: If the query returns value in DB level it should work in Informatica as well...can you try debugging the source ?

Answer (score -1):

If no data has been loaded after yesterday's load, then you can try the below query:

```
select count(*) from Table_name where DATEID=(select max(dateid) from Table_name)
```